# Why INNER JOIN dont not work correct?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have one SQL query with INNER JOINS. I need to get all offers from table `offers`.

Table `offers` is empty now. But the following query returns one row with NULL field.

Why is it returned? How to fix that? I need to return 0 rows if table is empty.

Query:

```
    select *, SUM(offers.price * announcement_product.amount) AS total, announcements.user_id AS creator_ann, announcements.id AS ann_id,
 announcements.delivery AS deliveryAnn, announcements.payment AS
 paymentAnn, SUM(announcement_product.amount) AS amount,
 announcement_product.name as name_product 
from `offers` 
inner join `announcements` on `announcements`.`id` = `offers`.`announcement_id` 
inner join `announcement_product` on `offers`.`announcement_product_id` = `announcement_product`.`id` 
inner join `countries` on `countries`.`id` = `announcements`.`country` 

where `offers`.`user_id` = 1 and `offers`.`status` = 1 and `offers`.`deleted_at` is null
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the aggregate function `SUM()`, but you don't have any `GROUP BY` clause.

When you do that you are instructing MySQL to add up all the row values in the column you mention in `SUM()`. It will do that even if there are no rows to add up.

For best results you should study up on the `GROUP BY` function and how to use it with `SUM()`.  It's hard to guess what you want from your query.

Comment: So, I need to use `GROUP BY` for field?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I don't think

`select *, ..`

when there's multiple tables in the query is valid.

Try

`select offers.*,..`

Answer (score 0):

This how Your select structure should be :
Select
    Id,
    Sku,
    Sum(Onhand),
    Sum(price)
From mytable 
           Where mytable Onhand > 0
               Group by 
                        Id,Sku
If you are going to use aggregate function such as Max,Sum,Min,....
you need to use group by for other table fields that your using in the select part.